# edit text widthsize problems with multiple screen

Tags: android

I have linear layout with 3 components `Button`, `EditText`, `Button`, my problem is my `EditText` size is fixed that are not working in tab, or some small screen devices.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/transparaent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/hashTag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/hash" >
    </Button>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtInUserSide"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/round_cornaeredittxt"
        android:hint="@string/findBusNumberSearch"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textSize="18sp" >
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendReq"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/send" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: where is edit text in this code?

Comment: You can give `weight` to that `UI` or make different layout folder in `res` folder for supporting multiple screen.

Comment: this already done piyush

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `EditText's` size is fixed because you fixed the size to `230dp`

```
 android:layout_width="230dp"
```

You can solve this problem using `android:layout_weight` attribute in `EditText` which will help you to support multiple-screen.

Set the value of `android:layout_width` to `0dip` and value of `android:layout_weight` to `1`.

```
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:layout_weight="1"
```